# Passing Data to Next Step in a Wicked Wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wizard

I just watched the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked) on the [Wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) used to create multi step wizards.

I was wondering if this gem could be used to create a wizard where data is passed forward somehow in the `render_wizard` call? Based on my initial tinkering, I do not believe that this is possible. The problem I hope to solve is to create a wizard where the first step takes a country and the second step allows the selection of people from that country.

Is there any easier way to solve this problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out this thread: https://github.com/schneems/wicked/issues/5

Comment: Does the data need to be passed by the `render_wizard` call? The wiki now contains a sample of collecting all the models params in the session: https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-objects-without-saving-to-the-database

Answer (score 2):

You could employ a table-less ruby object. Serialize it to the session before each show step and load it up from the session (merging in any new params) before each update step.

```
before_filter :initialize_wizard, on: [:show, :update]

...

def initialize_wizard
  @wizard = YourWizardTempModel.new
  @wizard.update_attributes(session['wizard']) if session['wizard'].present?
  @wizard.update_attributes(params['wizard']) if params['wizard'].present?
  session['wizard'] = @wizard.as_json
end
```

Then you could have a conditional before_filter that assembled the people selection based on the country_id like such:

```
before_filter :populate_people, if: "step == 'select_people'"

...

def populate_people
  People.find_by_country_id(@wizard.country_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ya you can pass data to the next step through the render method

```
render_wizard(@user, {}, { hello: 'world', your_param_key: "param value" })
```

here the params are

params[:hello] == "world"

params[:your_param_key] == "param value"

hope that helps anyone else in the future :)